# Reduce frequency of sitecore_analytics_index update/optimization

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Our content management server hosts the Lucene sitecore_analytics_index.

By default, the sitecore_analytics_index uses a TimedIndexRefreshStrategy with an interval of 1 minute. This means that every minute, Sitecore adds new analytics data to the index, and then optimizes the index.

We've found that the optimization part takes ~20 minutes for our index. In practice, this means that the index is *constantly* being optimized, resulting in non-stop high disk I/O.

I see two possible ways to improve the situation:

1. Don't run the optimize step after index updates, and implement an agent to optimize the index just once per day (as per [this post](https://reasoncodeexample.com/2015/03/18/throttling-lucene-index-optimizations-sitecore-7-content-search/)). Is there a big downside to only optimizing the index, say, once per day? AFAIK it's not necessary to optimize the index after every update.
2. Keep running the optimize step after every index update, but increase the interval from 1 minute to something much higher. What ill-effects might we see from this?

Option 2 is easier as it is just a config change, but I suspect that updating the index less frequently might be bad (hopefully I'm wrong?). Looking in the Sitecore search log, I see that the analytics index is almost constantly being searched, but I don't know what by, so I'm not sure what might happen if I reduce the index update frequency.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT: alternatively, what would be the impact of disabling the Sitecore analytics index entirely (and how could I do that)?

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/478/sitecore-index-update-jobs-getting-stuck

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think our situation differs in that we don't have a backlog of jobs building up and causing a problem - I simply want to stop the optimize step from running so frequently. I'd like to know what would be the impact of only running the optimize step once per day, or even disabling the analytics index entirely

Comment: We're actually in the same situation. Is there any update here?